# iTerm2 opens command response in vi like window

Tags: macos, shell, aws-cli, iterm2

I have iTerm Build 3.3.9 installed. I have configured `oh-my-zsh` with following plugins & themes

```
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k"

ZSH_DISABLE_COMPFIX="true"
plugins=(aws git colored-man-pages colorize github virtualenv pip python osx zsh-syntax-highlighting zsh-completions zsh-autosuggestions django npm zsh-interactive-cd zsh-navigation-tools)
```

Now there are 2 issues that i am trying to solve

1. See the [image: attached image], I have written the command uptil `aws cognito-i` and remaining is appearing as `autosuggestion`. the problem is that with my setup (probably theme but i have tried multiple themes) i am unable to distinguish between the command that i have typed and the command is being suggested. normally suggested command should appear a little dimmer but its the same color/opacity as the one that i have written. how to fix this
2. The second issue is that whenever i run a command with `aws cli` (also with `aws-nuke`, the response is opened with a new `vi` type window, i.e., the commands get removed and i see blank window with each line starting with `~` and at the end of the window it says `END`. Why is it happening and how to fix this as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the first issue try moving `zsh-syntax-highlighting` to the very end of `plugins`. From [zsh-syntax-highlighting FAQ](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting#faq):

> #### Why must `zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh` be sourced at the end of the `.zshrc` file?
>
> `zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh` wraps ZLE widgets.  It must be sourced
>   after all custom widgets have been created (i.e., after all `zle -N`
>   calls and after running `compinit`).  Widgets created later will work,
>   but will not update the syntax highlighting.

To fix the second issue add the following at the end of `~/.zshrc`:

```
# Use `less` as pager in Zsh.
READNULLCMD=less

# Use `less` as pager in external commands.
export PAGER=less

# This affects every invocation of `less`.
#
#   -i   case-insensitive search unless search string contains uppercase letters
#   -R   color
#   -F   exit if there is less than one page of content
#   -X   keep content on screen after exit
#   -M   show more info at the bottom prompt line
#   -x4  tabs are 4 instead of 8
export LESS=-iRFXMx4
```